# Pygame - find x and y given hypotenuse and angle

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

So I am going over a tutorial in python where I need to find x and y by given hypotenuse = 40 and the angle = 45 deg. Can anyone explain how to find the x and y?
[image: triangle]

Here is the code in python. Look at the movePlayer function. Finding the new x and y is done differently. The angle is first subtracted from 180 and then divided by 2 which doesn't make sense yet it work.

```
import pygame, math

pygame.init()

def movePlayer(direction, radius, absRot):
    yChange = 5
    # how many degrees to move in either side

    deltaTheta = int(90/(radius / yChange))

    if direction == 'left':
        deltaTheta *= -1

    # convert degrees to radians
    finalRot = (absRot + deltaTheta) * math.pi / 180

    hypotenuse = (radius * math.sin(finalRot) / (math.sin((math.pi - finalRot) / 2)))
    
    # why these work
    newX = hypotenuse * math.cos(math.pi/2-(math.pi - finalRot)/2)
    newY = hypotenuse * math.sin(math.pi/2-(math.pi - finalRot)/2)
    
    # these don't work
    #newX = hypotenuse * math.cos(math.pi/2-finalRot)
    #newY = hypotenuse * math.sin(math.pi/2-finalRot)


    return newX, newY,absRot + deltaTheta


WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 700
SCREEN_SIZE = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)


player = pygame.Surface((64,64))

playerStart = player
currentRotation = 0

ball = pygame.Surface((32,32))
ball.fill('red')

playerX = WIDTH // 2
playerY = 530
playerXOriginal = playerX
playerYOriginal = playerY

ballX = WIDTH // 2 - ball.get_rect().width // 2
ballY = 450 - ball.get_rect().height // 2

radius = playerY - ballY

FPS = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    pressedKeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressedKeys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        changeX, changeY, currentRotation = movePlayer('left', radius, currentRotation)
        playerX = playerXOriginal + changeX
        playerY = playerYOriginal - changeY
        print('left')
    elif pressedKeys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        changeX, changeY, currentRotation = movePlayer('right', radius, currentRotation)
        playerX = playerXOriginal + changeX
        playerY = playerYOriginal - changeY
        print('right')

    
    screen.fill('white')
    screen.blit(ball, (ballX,ballY))
    screen.blit(player, (playerX - player.get_rect().width //2,playerY - player.get_rect().height // 2))
    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: This is a math problem. For 45deg x and y are the same and x^2+y^2 = h^2

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the x,y coordinates, it's convenient to draw a straight line from (x,y) to make a right angle with the x-axis. Given the diagram, I will make the following two assumptions:

1. That the bottom left angle is 90 degree (which means it's an isosceles right triangle)
2. That the bottom right angle of the triangle is at the origin (the blue dot in the diagram).

Using the Pythagorean theorem, we get that x = - (40 / sqrt(2)) and y = 40 / sqrt(2).

To use the trigonometry, we get:

```
a, h = math.pi/4, 40
x, y = - h * cos(a), h * sin(a)
```

Comment: Thank you. What I don't understand is how to get the angle. The instructor does it like so

x = hypotenuse * math.cos(**math.pi/2-(math.pi - ang)/2**)
y = hypotenuse * math.sin(**math.pi/2-(math.pi - ang)/2**)

math.pi is 180, math.pi/2 is 90. So why from 180 we subtract angle and then divide by 2?

Comment: @JaredJunyoungLim it can be simplified to `ang/2` which still makes no sense

Comment: I agree that `ang/2` doesn't make sense, unless `ang` is referring to something else other than the blue-annotated angle in the diagram.

Comment: I've added the code in my question if it is any help!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat basic trigonometry (assuming ang is in radians and zero angle points towards +x).

```
x = cos(ang) * h
y = sin(ang) * h
```

Comment: You should probably point out that the angle expected by `cos` and `sin` must be in radians, not in degrees. The OP has a 45-degree angle. Degree angles can be converted to radians by multiplying them by `math.pi / 180`. In the case of 45 degrees or pi/4 radians, both the cosinus and the sinus are known to be equal (the figure in the question is misleading) and their exact value is `sqrt(2)/2`.

Comment: @Stef Yes, I... did point that out. "assuming ang is in radians".

Comment: Well, looking at the OP's comments on other answers, the OP really didn't seem to understand what that meant, and is confused because they're adding angles in degrees to angles in radians.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have an angle of 45 degrees, consequently you have a right isosceles triangle.

The general Pythagoras formula is : `h^2 = x^2 + y^2.`
Since the triangle is isosceles, then :

```
x = y => h^2 = 2 * x^2 => x = y = (sqrt(2)/2)*h
```

In a more general case, where the triangle is not isosceles:

```
x = cos(ang) * h
y = sin(ang) * h
```

In python:

```
import math 
def triangleSides(hypotenuse,angleindegrees):
    angleinradians  = (angleindegrees * math.pi / 180)
    (x,y) = hypotenuse* math.cos(angleinradians),hypotenuse* math.sin(angleinradians)
    return (x,y)
```

Comment: Thank you. However the instructor does it like so

x = hypotenuse * math.cos(**math.pi/2-(math.pi - ang)/2**)
y = hypotenuse * math.sin(**math.pi/2-(math.pi - ang)/2**)

Now sure why from 180 we subtract angle and then divide by 2?

Comment: @IvanYosifov but does the instructor get the same result? because whatever that is it seems completely wrong, depending on how `ang` is calculated, but even then those expressions can be simplified to `math.sin(ang/2)` and the same for `cos`

Comment: @Matiiss - yes his code works. I added the whole code in my question. If I try to implement it the way it has to be it doesn't work as expected